# Entity Framework: Update multiple rows in set with data from other set

Tags: entity-framework

I simply want to achieve this line of SQL:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.col = table2.col
FROM table2 INNER JOIN
     table1 ON table2.id = table1.id
```

How can that be done using Entity Framework with minimal number of round-trips?
All I can think of is using foreach to loop through my `table2` and update it's related entry in `table1`, but that leads to a whole lot of round-trips, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is, unfortunately, [no UPDATE in Entity SQL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387145.aspx) at present. A workaround is to [use regular SQL](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2007/12/07/rolling-your-own-sql-update-on-top-of-the-entity-framework-part-1.aspx). Without this, keep the number of round trips to a minimum by loading all required rows from both tables at once and calling SaveChanges as few times as possible.

Answer (score 0):

As Craig has said, there is no in-build support for multiple objects in EF, but you can build your own or use following link as reference.

http://geeks.ms/blogs/unai/archive/2008/07/17/multiple-entity-updates-with-entity-framework-ef-fetch-updates.aspx

http://efe.codeplex.com/

Both use same logic but efe provides a wrapper and some more functionality. Basically clean code. (Like that!). I hope this will help.

Sanjay Zalke